# How to send a Post request with multi parameter in body postman ? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I Write A Controller And want To Pass multi parameter in Postman But in controller only receive default values

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Server.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name, [FromBody] int age)
    {
        return Ok("id : " + id + "\n" + "name : " + name
        + "\n" + "age : " + age);
    }
}
```

I Try To send with raw body in postman ,
Bellow the request I Send To Postman

```
 "pararms" :
          {
            "id":10,
            "name":"Jone",
             "age" :15  
          }
```

or

```
      {
    "pararms" :
          {
            "id":10,
            "name":"Jone",
             "age" :15  
          }
      }
```

or

```
      {
            "id":10,
            "name":"sara",
             "age" :15  
      }
```

status in postman is 200 but value returned like bellow

id : 0
name :
age : 0

if question unclear tell me to edit it :)

Comment: Delete with a body is weird. Possibly Asp.net just ignores the body.

Comment: As a test you might try changing that to a POST instead and see if that behaves as expected. If yes Microsoft is on my side an thinks DELETE and body does not belong together.

Comment: nothing change , I Try Change Method To Post And Resend ,But Nothing Changed,  I Will Edit Question As Post Request

Comment: You write you used "raw" in Postman. Actually you can select "json" after that. There should be a dropdown selecting the concrete body type.

Comment: yes ,From The Start ,I Send As a json , if don't select json Format , Get unsupported media type Error

Comment: You can have only one FromBody. Create a model class to hold your parameters.

Comment: Yes , With Model Work Perfectly , You Say Can Only One FromBody , Is there any source that talks about it?